# Resize QStackedWidget to the page which is opened

Tags: qt, size, qwidget, qstackedwidget

I want my `QStackedWidget` to resize to the page which is opened.

I got a lot of widgets attached to the first page, but the rest pages have only one button. So they stay so big, and the first page is ok.

How can I make my `QStackedWidget` to have the size of the page being viewed.

The reason why i want to do this is that I have three different options, and after that I have other things. If I change to the mode where there is a button and then a lot of white space, I don´t see why doesn´t it resize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this [Resizable StackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_get_a_qstackedwidget_to_automatically_switch_size_depending_on_th)

In my practice i remember that i had class derived from QStackedWidget with redefined addWidget method. In this method i did next:

```
void ResizableStackedWidget::addWidget(QWidget* pWidget)
{
   pWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
   QStackedWidget::addWidget(pWidget);
}
```

And connected to currentChange(QWidget*) signal with this slot:

```
void ResizableStackedWidget::onCurrentChanged(int index)
{
   QWidget* pWidget = widget(index);
   Q_ASSERT(pWidget);
   pWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
   pWidget->adjustSize();
   adjustSize();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// make the stacked widget size to the current page only
for (int i = 0; i < m_ui->stackedWidget->count (); ++i)
{
    // determine the vertical size policy
    QSizePolicy::Policy policy = QSizePolicy::Ignored;
    if (i == m_ui->stackedWidget->currentIndex ())
        policy = QSizePolicy::Expanding;

    // update the size policy
    QWidget* pPage = m_ui->stackedWidget->widget (i);
    pPage->setSizePolicy (policy, policy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!   You do this every time? just when you create it? i don´t get it! sorry.When exactly do you do this?. I create all widgets, i add them... but i didn´t know you could set a policy for every page.

Comment: setting expanding to the pages, doesn´t work...

Comment: Whenever the current page changes do this

Comment: You need to have a good size policy on the QStackedWidget itself, and I seem to need to call adjustSize() on the QStackedWidget too after changing the page widgets' size policies.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. This should be added whenever the page changes, for example in the slot of stackedWidget::onCurrentChanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap pages with single button into QFrame with vertical layout and add spacer at bottom.